# Empty Bootcamp Partition Big Sur Macbook late 2013

Tags: boot-camp

When I create a bootcamp partition using bootcamp, windows does not boot and the bootcamp partition is empty with no files

Answer (score 0):

After you create the partition, you then have to install Windows in it (from a disk purchased from Microsoft).